# python pickle IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

Hi I'm working on a python text adventure and I got a save feature working that saved all main variables inventory, location and gold. Then I added in 2 more variables and it wouldn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Here's my working code.

```
def do_save(self, arg):
    saveGame = open('savegame.txt', 'wb')
    saveValues = (inventory, gold, location)
    pickle.dump(saveValues, saveGame)
    saveGame.close()

def do_load(self, arg):
    global inventory
    global gold
    global location
    global equiped
    global health
    loadGame = open('savegame.txt', 'rb')
    loadValues = pickle.load(loadGame)
    inventory = loadValues[0]
    gold = loadValues[1]
    location = loadValues[2]
    loadGame.close()
```

This is the code that isn't working

```
def do_save(self, arg):
    saveGame = open('savegame.txt', 'wb')
    saveValues = (inventory, gold, location, equiped, health)
    pickle.dump(saveValues, saveGame)
    saveGame.close()

def do_load(self, arg):
    global inventory
    global gold
    global location
    global equiped
    global health
    loadGame = open('savegame.txt', 'rb')
    loadValues = pickle.load(loadGame)
    inventory = loadValues[0]
    gold = loadValues[1]
    location = loadValues[2]
    equiped = loadValues[3]
    health = loadValues[4]
    loadGame.close()
```

The error message I'm getting is IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: What's the exact error with trace? `loadValues` probably doesn't contain as many elements as you think it does. Have you verified what it contains?

Comment: The 2 snippets seem correct at 1st glance. Are you sure you're not mixing `do_save` from the 1st snippet and `do_load` from the 2nd one? Try printing `loadValues` before doing anything with it. Also, `arg` doesn't seem to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution but it may not be the most efficient way here is the code

```
def do_save(self, arg):
    saveGame = open('savegame.txt', 'wb')
    saveValues = (inventory, gold, location, equiped, health)
    saveValues1 = (equiped, health)
    pickle.dump(saveValues, saveGame)
    pickle.dump(saveValues1, saveGame)
    saveGame.close()

def do_load(self, arg):
    global inventory
    global gold
    global location
    global equiped
    global health
    loadGame = open('savegame.txt', 'rb')
    loadValues = pickle.load(loadGame)
    inventory = loadValues[0]
    gold = loadValues[1]
    location = loadValues[2]
    equiped = loadValues[3]
    health = loadValues[4]
    loadGame.close()
    displayLocation(location)
```